# dockerfile to deploy to tomcat server does not display webapp

Tags: maven, docker, tomcat, jenkins

I am using Jenkins to deploy a maven hello-world file to a docker tomcat image. the mvn clean package command works well in the jenkins job, and the subsequent dockerfile spawns an image where the webapp.war file will be placed in tomcat home directory.(/usr/local/tomcat/webapp/webapp.war)
This is supposed to display o/p on the tomcat page running over port 8181, but i cannot get it to work.[The tomcat is working though](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q7B4.png)

The Repo which contains the Jenkinsfile and Dockerfile is https://github.com/Kush-2806/Maven-Docker-CI

[This is the output instead of the hello world](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvJrp.png)

Comment: This will build your image - but how do you start the container then? Are you doing that manually afterwards? I am concerned that you are looking at a previously deployed tomcat container without your application deployed.

Comment: I go to the terminal, check for the images i have, and run the latest version. Then localhost to the port.
It will be the latest version cz the Dockerfile indexes the versions concurrent to the jenkins  build number. so if i just built my project on build #10, my tomcat image will have version 10 with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/Kush-2806/Maven-Docker-CI/blob/master/Dockerfile).

The directory is called **`/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/`**, so you are just one **`s`** short - in your Dockerfile you copy to this location `/usr/local/tomcat/webapp/`

Update the `Dockerfile` to this:

```
FROM tomcat:8.0

ADD ./webapp/target/*.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Now visit the site http://localhost:8181/webapp

Comment: I entered the container with bash, and i checked that the webapp.war file is stored in the 'webapp' directory. Agreed there is another 'webapps' dir but thats not where the war file is stored.

Comment: That is because you copied it there in your Dockerfile. You need to copy it to the `webapps` directory in order for tomcat to mount it. The webapp directory was created when you copied the file there. Try the code that I pasted above.

Comment: I actually tried that, and it worked (Thank You!). I still cannot understand though, if all files under /usr/local/tomcat/ are visible, then why can't I just put this in any folder of my choice and try to run it on tomcat?

Comment: The .war package is mounted by tomcat as a java web application - it only does this out of the `webapps` location. Other static content can be served from the web root I guess. Can you accept the answer then?

Comment: Understood, Thank you.